# How to restart activity and clear player status?

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I am creating a quiz game with 3 player lives (hearts). Player has 3 tries to get correct answer. If the player gets the correct answer before the hearts go to 0 a new level is created. Now my problem is

How do I restart my gameplay activity when player hearts==0 and clear player status, load back to level 1 and set new 3 hearts?

```
Private void showResult(){
        for(int b = 0; b<4; b++){
            answers[b].setOnClickListener(null);
        }


if(hearts==0){
        resultCoins.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resultImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.smile);
        loadLevel.setText("CONTINUE");
        resultTxt.setText("Correct is: "+answers[correctAnswer-1].getText());
        loadLevel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(GamePlay.this, "Game Over, Press Back to Return", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, write `this.recreate();`. This is the shortest solution for your question, it will destroy the activity and call `onCreate` and so on lifecycle methods.
Also, you can create a method that resets your models and views to their initial state. 
 It is preferred not to recreate your activities as a part of your application main flow.

Comment: hi.. I tried to do recreate but I am unable to get the result that I am expecting.. Anyway thanks for the reply